# Max throws NullReferenceException when used with DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: c#, linq

I have following class structure and I need to find the most recent `UpdatedDate` for `Order` i.e. Max of `Order / Orderline / OrderlineSize / OrderlineVAS`. The lists are never null but might be empty.

```
class Order
{
    public List<Orderline> Orderlines { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

class Orderline
{
    public List<OrderlineSize> OrderLineSizes { get; set; }
    public List<OrderlineVAS> OrderLineValueAddedServices { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
class OrderlineSize
{
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

class OrderlineVAS
{
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following code to get `Max` which works fine if there are some `OrderLineSizes` but throws a `NullReferenceException` when list is empty.

```
(new List<DateTime?>() {
    order.UpdatedDate,
    order.Orderlines.Max(x=>x.UpdatedDate),
    order.Orderlines.SelectMany(x=>x.OrderLineSizes).DefaultIfEmpty()?.Max(y=>y.UpdatedDate),
    order.Orderlines.SelectMany(x=>x.OrderLineValueAddedServices).DefaultIfEmpty()?.Max(y=>y.UpdatedDate)
})
.Max().Value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
```

I have solved it using elvis operation from C# 6 as below

```
(new List<DateTime?>() {
    order.UpdatedDate,
    order.Orderlines.Max(x=>x?.UpdatedDate),
    order.Orderlines.SelectMany(x=>x.OrderLineSizes).Max(y=>y?.UpdatedDate),
    order.Orderlines.SelectMany(x=>x.OrderLineValueAddedServices).Max(y=>y?.UpdatedDate)
})
.Max().Value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
```

How could it be solved using earlier versions of `C#`? I reckon the use of `Select` clause in Linq but not sure if that is a good option. 
How can I optimize it for better performance?

Comment: `Select` is good enough option. `.Select(x => x.UpdatedDate).DefaultIfEmpty().Max()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is being thrown from:

```
.DefaultIfEmpty()?.Max(y=>y.UpdatedDate)
```

DefaultIfEmpty does not return null. Rather, it returns an enumerable with a single null entry. Therefore it passes through the ?. to Max. Finally the null is processed at y.UpdateDate with y == null, causing the NullReferenceException.

Resolve by removing the ? from after DefaultIfEmpty, and instead add it after y as follows:

```
.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(y=>y?.UpdatedDate)
```

This needs to be done in both lines that this pattern appears.

Also, the whole thing can be made more efficient and succinct with:

```
        string result =                
            Enumerable.Repeat(order.UpdatedDate, 1)
                .Concat(order.Orderlines.Select(x1 => x1.UpdatedDate))
                .Concat(order.Orderlines.SelectMany(x => x.OrderLineSizes).Select(x => x.UpdatedDate))
                .Concat(order.Orderlines.SelectMany(x => x.OrderLineValueAddedServices).Select(x => x.UpdatedDate))
                .Max().ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
```